# IF IF issue to work out percentage

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am having issues getting an equation to work.
Short of it is this. I have a column with cost, one with Recommended sell price, and one with a manual price to override the recommended.
I need a formula to work out the percentage based on the RRP if the manual price is blank, but change the percentage if a manual price is put in. Below is a sample of what I have.

```
         C          D            E            F 
       Cost       RRP          Manual        Percentage
       30         1000       2000          1500         ??
       31         1000       2000                       ??
```

I have tried

```
=IF(C30>=0,IF(E30>0,((E30-C30)/E30)),0)
```

But it will not override the ppercentage of `F30`, `F31` etc.

Sorry about the jumble at the bottom. Should have been

```
C30=1000, D30=2000, E30=1500, F30=??
C31=1000, D31=2000, E31=BLANK, F31=??
```

Hope this makes sense.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "override" the percentage?  Is the formula you gave above being entered into cell `F30` ?

Comment: If the cost is 100, RRP is 200, percentage will be 50%. If I put a figure of 150 into the manual box, I need the percentage to change to 25% and override the 50%. It is to figure out profit percentage on sales.

Comment: So that this is clear for everyone, if `manual` is empty you have one formula, and otherwise there is a different formula?

Comment: Yes, correct. If the manual box is empty it works out the percentage of "C" and "D". If manual is filled it works out percentage of "C" and "E"

Comment: Just in case people struggle working out percentages.    (RRP-COST)/RRP=%

Comment: `=IF(C30>=0,IF(E30>0,(E30-C30)/E30,(D30-C30)/D30),0)`